# Eclipse download ftp files

Tags: eclipse

How do I copy files/directories from the Remote Systems panel in Eclipse to my hard-drive using FTP? I'm already logged in and can view/edit the files.

I'm using Eclipse 3.8.1 on Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I've found the answer to this question when nobody else did I will share it here:

- Right click the folder you want to download and select `synchronize cache`.
- When Eclipse has finished synchronizing (AKA downloading, since this is the first time you did it) the directory, you can find it in your selected workspace inside a folder called `RemoteSystemsTempFiles`